# Loading GeoJSON data into Leaflet map using getJSON problem

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I've a problem loading GeoJSON data into Leaflet map using getJSON. None of the GeoJSON data is displaying. The basemap & two circles are showing so it looks like Leaflet is working as expected. Both of these files are local & in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Base 1_71</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="osmtogeojson.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {padding: 0;margin: 0;}
            html, body, #map {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var osm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {opacity: 0.7});
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.3718,-2.3460], 14).addLayer(osm);
                    var Radius = 2000
            L.circle([51.3813864, -2.3596963], {radius: Radius,opacity: .5,fillOpacity: 0}).addTo(map);

            $.getJSON("TTCircuitWays.geojson", function (data) {
            L.geoJson(data, {
                color: 'red',
                weight: 3,
                opacity: 1,
            }).addTo(map);
        }); 
        L.circle([51.3823864, -2.3596963], {radius: Radius,opacity: 1,fillOpacity: 0}).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Geojson data:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "generator": "overpass-ide",
  "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.",
  "timestamp": "2021-06-08T18:49:49Z",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "relation/4137412"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [[[-2.3659215,51.3822893],[-2.3581637,51.3829442]],[[-2.3567509,51.3834819],[-2.357133,51.3833276],[-2.3576093,51.3831429],[-2.3576622,51.3831224],[-2.3581637,51.3829442]],[[-2.3521667,51.3852626],[-2.3518664,51.3854071],[-2.3518386,51.3854365],[-2.3518186,51.3854736],[-2.3517752,51.3855541]]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What's strange is that this & other examples I've written worked a couple of years ago and even internet examples such as this one fail:
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap1.html

Comment: Loading map from server or from file system? Any errors in the browser debugger console and/or network section?

Comment: Looks like an axis order issue to me - or does leaflet use a lat/lon order by default?

Comment: @IanTurton In API calls Leaflet uses lat/lon order by default, see for example https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#latlng. GeoJSON data retains standard lon/lat coordinate order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GeoJSON loads just fine for me. Are you making sure to load your script through a server (e.g. using Python [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html))? Could be a CORS issue if you're trying to load the GeoJSON locally.

[image]

Comment: Yes Looking at the console as @TomazicM suggested, it looks like it's a 'CORS' issue. Turn off privacy.file_unique_origin in Firefox as described [here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp) & it loads. 

I'm confused as to why FF thinks there's a security risk loading from my local hard drive but allows download of data from a remote server.
As this is just for my usage is setting up an http:server the best/simplest way forward or is it safe for me to keep privacy check off?

Comment: I would avoid turning off that privacy option, setting up a Python server is simple enough, you just need to make sure your file is named `index.html` and Python does the rest!

Comment: Thanks. I'm having problems setting up the server. I've posted a separate question [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1655932/set-up-of-a-python-http-web-server-is-hanging). If you have a minute I'd appreciate any help.